# Why is my code not returning 0? I'm using scanf() instead of cin

Tags: c++, scanf

I wanted to make sure I understood how to use `scanf()`, but I don't understand why my code didn't return 0. I understand that `scanf()` has it's own issue when it comes to loops, etc, but it bewilders me how something as simple as displaying a string wouldn't return 0.

Is there perhaps any problems with my code?

My simple code to type and display a name is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string name[15];
  printf("Please type your name: ");
  scanf("%s", &name);
  printf("Your name is %s", name);
  return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
Your name is hello
Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)   execution time : 4.356 s
Press any key to continue.
```

while if I use `cin`/`cout` instead of `scanf()`/`printf()`,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    cout << "Please type your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Your name is: " << name;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please type your name: hello
Your name is: hello
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.794 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", &name);` to `scanf("%s", name);` or better `scanf("%15s", name);`

Comment: It's only happenstance that either sample of code compiles at all.  `<iostream>` is not guaranteed to give `std::string` (use `<string>` for that) or C I/O  (use `<cstdio>`).   If those things are fixed,  `printf()` and `scanf()` do not work with `std::string`, so the behaviour of your first sample is undefined.   The `%s`  format assumes a raw array of `char`, not a `std::string`.

Comment: It shouldn't bewilder you that even simple programs are complex enough that it's easy to make mistakes. That's the nature of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first program has undefined behavior.

`scanf` and `printf` expect for the `%s` a pointer to `char`, not a pointer to `std::string`. They are C library functions and as such don't know anything about C++ types such as `std::string`. You are required to provide the correct type as argument for the format specifier. If you don't, your program has undefined behavior.

So, in the first code block, you need to replace

```
string name[15];
```

with

```
char name[15];
```

Note that this is still unsafe, because you will access the array out-of-bounds if the user inputs a string longer than 14 characters, again causing undefined behavior with that input.

Also, enable warnings in your compiler, e.g. with the compiler flags

```
-Wall -Wextra
```

in GCC and Clang. It is likely that the compiler will then warn you about the wrong argument type.

In addition, replace `#include<iostream>` by `#include<cstdio>` in the first program. `scanf` and `printf` are provided by the standard library header `<cstdio>`. `<iostream>` is not guaranteed to include them. Similarly the second program requires an additional `#include<string>`, because `<iostream>` is also not guaranteed to provide `std::string`.

Comment: @xhar12345 Be aware that both programs (with the fixes mentioned above) are C++ programs, but not valid C programs. In a C program the header should be `stdio.h` instead of `cstdio` and there shouldn't be a `using namespace std;` (really, this is often considered bad practice in C++ as well, because it can easily cause name clashes). While a big subset of C is valid C++, the inverse is not true and best practices in both languages are completely different. You should probably stick to learning one of the two.

Comment: Also worth noting that `string name[15];` does not give you a `std::string` with space for 15 characters, instead it gives you an array of 15 `std::string`s that each can contain any number of characters. Whereas `char name[15];` only gives you a single C-string that can only contain 15 characters.